# How can I change the color of elements in a tag with tailwindcss

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I have a font awesome icon and a text inside an `<a>` in tailwindcss. The default color is blue because it is an `href`. How can I change this color with tailwindcss.
This is the code I have so far

```
<a
      class="bg-dark-150"
      href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.url }}"
      onclick="window.open(this.href, 'pop-up', 'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;"
      title="Share on Facebook"
    >
      <i class="fa fa-facebook-official share-button"> facebook</i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your text inside span tag and then apply styling

```
 <body >
        <a
            class="bg-dark-150"
            href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.url }}"
            onclick="window.open(this.href, 'pop-up', 'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;"
            title="Share on Facebook"
        >
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-official share-button"> <span class="text-white "> facebook </span> </i>
        </a>
    </body>
```